# *Urgent* American citizen studying in the UK. Flight leaves tomorrow, visa in processing and no biometrics?

Tags: visas, usa, uk

Can I enter the UK as a visitor, while my visa is in processing and have my biometrics done there? Or do I have to come back to the USA? I only recently received my CAS and there were no biometric appointments available before my flight.

*Edit I have a passport and intend to come back to North America for Christmas. Would it be okay for me to stay until then on a visitor visa and if my Tier 4 PBS student visa is accepted - return in the new year?

Comment: What kind of visa? US citizens don't *need* a visa to enter the UK, provided they're staying for a short period of time (<6 months  and have no criminal convictions/history of overstays) and are not working in the UK.

Comment: @CMaster, visa notwithstanding the OP would still need a passport :)

Comment: @GayotFow This is very true. Hadn't occured to me that "Visa in processing" probably meant handed over passport. They might have 2 passports though I guess?

Comment: Where are you going to get a visitor visa from, if your student visa isn't ready yet?

Comment: I only have one passport.

Comment: Since I'm an American citizen I believe I'm allowed to visit for up to six months? At least that is how it was two years ago.

Comment: Yes, but that's having the visa waived, not on a general visitor visa. As a US citizen, you *can* get a general visitor visa if you are worried you might be refused entry, but that's not going to arrive any quicker than your student visa. Take a look at https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration . (I think I may be able to answer this one, but I imagine @GayotFow can do a better job, I might get it wrong)

Comment: @CMaster, the OP is flirting with abuse, possibly with having their CAS revoked.  You're welcome to answer.  You should cite Paragraph 245ZU.

Comment: @GayotFow See, that's why I won't. No idea what you're talking about, my knowledge is limited to the info on the likes of gov.uk and embassy sites. Not got the time to read the full docs.

Comment: @CMaster, note the answer. It comes up every September so you'll be in good shape next time.  (Closed in favour of Expats, so up votes will be cancelled)

Answer (score 9):

No.  Please read [Paragraph 245ZU](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/449496/20150803_immigration_rules_part_6a_final.pdf) of the rules...

> All migrants arriving in the UK and wishing to enter as a Tier 4 (General) Student must have a valid entry clearance for entry under this route. If they do not have a valid entry clearance, entry will be refused.

Your sponsor will get into trouble if you attempt to study as a visitor when the course requires a T4. When sponsors get into trouble, they tend to revoke the person's CAS. If the trouble was caused by the student (like in your case), they will not issue another CAS to them.  When they sent you the stuff, they advised you (along with the guidance) **not to make travel plans until the visa was issued**.

Additionally, they will not let a person enrol their biometrics from within the UK as part of a T4 application.  That was the whole point of introducing biometrics as an entry clearance requirement.  Also, trying to get a T4 from within the UK will lead to a refusal with possible removal instructions and then matters will be worse.  **Americans are not exempt from these rules.**

We can answer here because it's urgent; your follow-up questions should be posted on the [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions) site.

Comment: And this is why the visa you were waiting for/reason for wishing to nter matters.